# How to save file in a folder in windows application

Tags: c#, windows

I want to send an attachment in an email, SO for that I want to save the attachment file in a folder first.

> So what's happening with my current code is, the mail is going with attachment but my file is not getting saved into the `ATTACHMENT` folder.

here is the code i tried

```
for (int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            if (1 == 1)
            {
                string StrPriBody = "This is a test mail for checking notification.";

                MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
                mail.Subject = "Daily Holding followup scheduler";
                mail.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("autosupport@powersoft.in");
                SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
                smtp.Timeout = 1000000;
                smtp.Port = Convert.ToInt32(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Port"]);
                smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
                smtp.Host = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MailHost"];
                smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(mail.From.ToString(), "PS123456");
                smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                mail.To.Add(new MailAddress("abc@test.com"));
                mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
                mail.Body = StrPriBody;

                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                ds.Tables.Add(table);
                ds.Tables[0].TableName = "Post sale follow up entries auto mailer";


                SaveFileDialog save = new SaveFileDialog();
                save.InitialDirectory = "\\Attachment";
                save.RestoreDirectory = true;

                ExcelLibrary.DataSetHelper.CreateWorkbook("Employee_Details.xls", ds);

                mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment("Employee_Details.xls"));

                smtp.Send(mail);

                foreach (Attachment attachments in mail.Attachments)
                {
                    attachments.Dispose();
                }
```

Comment: And why your file should be saved in the Attachment folder? How do you tell to your ExcelLibrary to create the file in that folder?

Comment: @Steve: I have no idea how to create that in folder? any help

Comment: You don't need a SaveFile dialog to do that (and in your code you define it but you are not using it). Just use [File.Copy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.copy(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: The call to CreateWorkBook takes a filename, but without a path the file is created (probably) in the current directory. The Attachment constructor finds the file for the same reason, you don't specify a folder and thus the file is expected to be in the current directory. If you want to add the Attachment path then you should use Path.Combine to add it to your filename

Comment: You do not even need to save a file to the disk as the .Net Mail client can append attachements directly from a `MemoryStream` provided that you append a mime type and a name.

Comment: @Pikoh: any help with the code would be great

Comment: @Steve: sorry sir didn't got u. Some code would be great

Comment: @Adwaenyth: can u show with some code, that would be great

Comment: @learner there is an article about using Open XML Documents in Memory [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericwhite/2008/12/10/working-with-in-memory-open-xml-documents/) and [this](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Attach-File-from-MemoryStream-to-MailMessage-object-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx) explains how to use a `MemoryStream` to add an attachment to a mail.

Comment: @Adwaenyth: thanks, will surely look at it.!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a SaveFileDialog to do that (and in your code you define it but you are not using it). Just use [File.Copy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.copy(v=vs.110).aspx). So, after creating your Workbook here:

```
ExcelLibrary.DataSetHelper.CreateWorkbook("Employee_Details.xls", ds);
```

Just add something like:

```
File.Copy("Employee_Details.xls","\\Attachment\Employee_Details.xls");
```

Comment: getting error as `Could not find a part of the path '\Attachment\Employee_Details.xls'.`

Comment: @learner, I don't know the path where you want to save that file. I just must exist. If the folder is "c:\attachments", then change the second argument of the File.Copy method to that

Comment: Pikoh: my attachment folder is in the root folder so what should be the path ?

Comment: Try `File.Copy("Employee_Details.xls",@"\Attachment\Employee_Details.xls");`

Comment: Then try `File.Copy("Employee_Details.xls",@"d:\Attachment\Employee_Details.xls");`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109800/discussion-between-learner-and-pikoh).

Answer (score 0):

1) Why you are using `SaveFileDialog`? User must choose folder and file name to save to? Then you forgot to "display" dialog, and after user close it - retrieve chosen folder/file name from it and (preferably) use full path (C:\Folder\File...) for `CreateWorkbook` and `new Attachment(...)`.

2) Are you sure that after call to `ExcelLibrary.DataSetHelper.CreateWorkbook` this file is actually written to disk with content? May be you need to call some `Save()` methods? (this is library-specific, read in library docs)

3) Are you sure that after call to `ExcelLibrary.DataSetHelper.CreateWorkbook` new file is closed/unlocked by writing code? May be you need to `Dispose` something? (again, check library docs)

4) Are you testing on server (website?) or desktop machine? Check that you can write access to folder where you want to store your file.

Comment: i am testing on desktop machine, what I want is the mail needs to be sent with an excel attachment and the attachment shd also get in the folder